# AWS Appsync multiple dynamodb requesst in one dynamodb resolver

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync, resolver

I would like to know if it is possible to have multiple dynamodb request using only one dynamo resolver in AppSync? 
Or the only/best way to have more complicated processing is to use a lambda function ?

Answer (score 0):

Practically, no. You even cannot query on multiple indices in a single resource definition for an query, indeed.

However, if you are to use that structure for *joining* multiple DynamoDB tables, you can attach resolvers not to the query entry; but to the field you want to relate on other fields.

I had an issue like relating users to another table for containing the posts and I've passed it by attaching a resolver aiming the *Posts* field of the *User* type.

This issue refers to a similar problem and is quite helpful for that kind of cases: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/issues/17

If it is not the case of yours, you can elaborate the question. I may look like guessing your purpose for relating tables, all in all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had looked into the issue and indeed I attach resolvers to field in order to query into multiple table. What I wanted to do now, was to query a table B using data of a first query of table A. But I didn't know if it was possible with VTL and inside one resolver. Because all the example that I found there was first some processing using vtl and then a dynamo template query. I guess it is not possible, and so to do this kind of processing I will need to use lambda functions

Comment: Fair enough, still an option Lambda is -a cheap one indeed :) Personally, I want my AppSync resolvers as direct as possible, but it is me. Good luck, anyways.

Comment: Using cascading resolver you can use $ctx.source.*fieldFromParentQuery* to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at batch resolvers with AWS AppSync?https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html

This will allow you to write to one or more tables in a single request, and also allow you to do multiple write/read/delete operations in a single request.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pipeline resolvers
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-pipeline-resolvers.html